# How to measure agreement with categorical labels, and with multiple binary labels?

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding, agreement-statistics, multilabel

I have a dataset in which 7 coders have given a categorical label to each of 152 objects. The same 8 categories are selected between for all objects. I would like to measure the agreement between coders, across the dataset as a whole, as well as within particular labels. The questions I would like to ask/quantify are:

1. How well do raters agree on the categorical labels across this dataset?
2. Are some labels more prone to being agreed upon than others?
3. Are some pairs or groups of labels interchangeable? (I'm thinking of a confusion matrix, but in this context there's no ground-truth labels).

The coders have also marked 6 binary labels on each object (yes/no - does this object have this property). Again, the 6 properties are the same for each object. For this multi-label data, I would like to ask how well the coders agree on the labels as a whole, as well as each individual property label.

What would be appropriate measures for asking these questions?